# Error loading extension with localization

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromium, nwjs

My nw.js app suddenly stopped working on Windows 10 with the following error;

```
Failed to load extension from {path}. Default locale is defined but default data couldn't be loaded.
```

Structure & manifest

```
_locales
 en
js/i18n.js
```

Manifest

```
"default_language": "en"
```

I don't know what windows has changed recently but it has been working solidly on previous versions of Windows for years. I've updated the country tag as per available language packs for windows [here](https://www.windowscentral.com/windows-10-april-2018-changelog) and chromium tags but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=57370) :

> "I use Chrome and stopped updating it once they made tabbed-options
>   mandatory. I also keep my User Data folder in a non-default location.
>   When this bug started, I used the --single-process trick for a while
>   but as mwalsher said, it stopped working when they messed with the Web
>   Store. I used but hate the manual method outlined above, so what I did
>   was to simply move my User Data folder to a FAT32 partition. Problem
>   solved; now I can successfully install packed extensions from an older
>   version of Chromium, running in normal mode, to a non-default User
>   Data folder. Even better, thanks to a system I set up
>   (http://superuser.com/questions/196886/how-to-relocate-chrome-profile-but-also-make-new-links-open-with-the-relocated-p/257706#257706),
>   it was /extremely/ easy to change it (I had only to change a single
>   byte and reboot)."

..

> "Change the security permissions of the temp directory might fix this
>   problem.  On my computer, the temp directory only has 3 full control
>   user (My Account, System, Administrators) at beginning.  I manually
>   give everyone full control to this folder (maybe adding list
>   permission only also works).  However it doesn't work immediately,
>   until next day I restart the computer with great surprise.

..

> As a workaround, --no-sandbox might work. Note that this is just as
>   unsafe as --single-process, so be careful when using it.
>       ..
>
> ..
>   perform a "chrome://restart

Try [this first](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/1070):

> ..I restarted Chrome and tried to install it again, and now it
>   installed cleanly..

Comment: I have solved it but I don't really know the reason to be honest. I think the problem was with the way the executable was created and Win10 didn't like it. I had used Enigma Virtual Box. I recreated an executable with the latest Enigma Virtual Box and it's solved the issue.